# Insert new value into a vector such that the first element is always the newly inserted one

Tags: r, vector, append

```
example<-c(1,2,3)
to_be_inserted<-1

example<-append(example, to_be_inserted)
```

The result I got is `c(1,2,3,1)` however I would like `c(1,1,2,3)`

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the **append** function.

```
> append(1,example)
[1] 1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `c` to concatenate the vector.

```
c(to_be_inserted, example)
#[1] 1 1 2 3
```